# When NULL cannot be replaced by nullptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, null, nullptr

I am refactoring some older code that uses `NULL` in many places. The question is

> Is it safe to blindly replace all `NULL` instances by `nullptr`?

I am particularly interested in scenario where replacing NULL by `nullptr` may lead to some run-time errors (compile-time errors would be ok) but I can't think of any. If not, would it be safe to just auto-replace NULL by nullptr (fixing compile time errors if any).

I apologize if question have been asked earlier - I couldn't find it, I will delete it if you point me to the answer!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In practice it should be fairly safe.

But, technically, it *is* possible that the meaning of your program changes, without causing any compiler errors. Consider the [following program](http://ideone.com/jfH5NH):

```
void foo(int) { std::cout << "int\n"; }
void foo(int*) { std::cout << "int*\n"; }

int main() {
    foo(NULL);       // prints 'int'
    foo(nullptr);    // prints 'int*'
    return 0;
}
```

Note that when there's ambiguity between an `int` and a pointer when passing `NULL`, the pointer version is what's almost always desired -- which means that most real programs won't have an ambiguity like that in the first place (or will use casts like `(int*)NULL` to get around it, in which case replacement by `nullptr` is perfectly fine).

Comment: Worth noting that a C++11 compiler *could* legally define `NULL` as `nullptr`, though in practice none does because it would break too much existing code with people writing crazy stuff like `char c = NULL;` and the like.